# Clear previous responses in main activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple form in the main activity. On submitting the form, activity 2 starts. When I go back to the main activity (by clicking on the back button), I want to clear all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite onResume() in your main activity and clear the corresponding EditTexts there like

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    editText.setText("");

}
```

or

You can overwrite onBackPressed() in activity 2 like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: This code will only add more activities to the task stack, and I think that is not the behavior the app should have.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an `id` to any widget, and the activity or fragment stop, then the `onSaveState` is called for any widget to save the actual value and show it when you come back to that activity.

So, to clean up your EditText when you came back from another activity you'll have to do it manually, I suggest you to do it in `onRestart` function according to the Activity life cycle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an elegant solution, but it should works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean secondActivityLaunched;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                secondActivityLaunched = true;
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (secondActivityLaunched) {
            secondActivityLaunched = false;
            clearForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st Activity: MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.activitytest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent it=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
            it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
            finish();

        }
    });

    }
}
```

2nd Activity: Activity2.java

```
package com.test.activitytest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent it=new Intent(Activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(it);
    finish();

    }
}
```